# Why we don't need to provide initial value for local variables?

Tags: ios, swift

While I was learning suddenly I wondered myself:
why do we have to provide initial values for global(even beyond a class scope) variable but we do not have to do same step with local variables like this? Is there any reason?

```
if importRequired {
    let deleteObjectCount: Int    
}
```

Comment: Because the Swift compiler does definitive initialization analysis of local variables, but not on global variables. https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=28

Comment: @N.Khasanov Please accept the answer below if it is sufficient, to "close" this topic

Comment: Sorry, already done)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is allowed, because `deleteObjectCount` is never been used in your code. And - and this is the difference to global variables - this fact can be checked by the compiler.

You could even do something like:

```
let importRequired = true

if importRequired {
    let deleteObjectCount: Int    
    deleteObjectCount = 5
    print (deleteObjectCount)
}
```

(e.g. kind-of modify a constant `let` variable) because the compiler checks that the constant is written only *once*, and this is done *before* reading it's value.

In contrast, global variables must be initialized directly, because otherwise the compiler cannot guarantee that they have been so before being initialized (because the could be accessed from anywhere in your program).

Comment: Thank you for your help!